# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when using X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssl, client-certificates

I have a Web API that requires Client Certificate Authentication, Whenever I provide correct Client Certificate I get an error Could not Create  SSL/TLS Secure Channel.

My app is hosted on IIS Server from where I am accessing the API.
While executing the API through code I can get the desired result but when the app is hosted on IIS and then if the request is executed then I get the error.

My Code :

```
     myHttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(New X509Certificate2(certificate, myService.CertificateSettings.Certificate_Password.Decrypt))
     Dim response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

this can be complex to resolve - you can ignore these errors using the following code - not recommended...

```
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => {      
      return true;
   };
```

Alternatively examine the error and try to fix your certificate:

```
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
        {
            SslPolicyErrors result = errors;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        };
```

What SSL policy errors do you get?